# How can I direct the Y-axis downward and make the plot symmetrical to the X-axis?

Tags: plotting

How can I direct the Y-axis downward and make the plot symmetrical to the X-axis?

```
ParametricPlot[
  {0.06677273831511694 (1 - Exp[-8.145 t]), 
   -0.10917030600597447 (1 - Exp[-8.145 t]) + 1.2031921424186618 t}, 
  {t, 0, 2.6}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., 3.0191292643518968`}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the axes symmetrical, use [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio)->1. To reverse the y-axis, use [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions):

```
ParametricPlot[
    {
    0.06677273831511694*(1-Exp[(-8.145*t)]),
    -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t
    },
    {t,0,2.6},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ScalingFunctions->{None,"Reverse"}
]
```

[image]